# Rails - RestClient Unauthorized (401) Error, user is not recognized for POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, redmine, rest-client

I am working on a plugin for Redmine and I created a method which sends two HTTP requests (using POST method) to attach a new file to a document.

The first request works well (see Webrick console below)

```
Started POST "/redmine/uploads.json?attachment_id=1&filename=testFile.txt" for <server_IP_address> at 2014-04-04 11:37:58 +0200 
Processing by AttachmentsController#upload as JSON 
Parameters: {"attachment_id"=>"1", "filename"=>"testFile.txt"} 
Current user: <user> (id=3) 
Saving attachment '/home/user/Redmine/redmine-2.4.2/files/2014/04/140404113759_testFile.txt' (72 bytes)
Rendered attachments/upload.api.rsb (1.2ms) 
Completed 201 Created in 661.6ms (Views: 82.6ms | ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)
```

Then the second request is executed:

```
Started POST "/redmine/documents/150/add_attachment.xml" for <server_IP_address> at 2014-04-04 11:37:59 +0200 
Processing by DocumentsController#add_attachment as XML 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<auth_token>", "attachments"=>{"1"=>{"filename"=>"testFile.txt", "description"=>"Dropbox blabla", "token"=>"<upToken>"}}, "commit"=>"Add", "id"=>"150"} 
Current user: anonymous 
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected 
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 132.6ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

I get this error because the Current user here is `anonymous` (I think), I don't understand why, if I print a `User.current` after the first request the user is still logged.

I created the first request using the `net/http` library ant the second using `RestClient`, here is my code:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://<server_IP_address>/redmine/uploads.json")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
file = File.new("/home/testFile.txt") 
@csrfToken = session[:_csrf_token]
@apiKey = User.current.api_key

@request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path+"?attachment_id=1&filename=testFile.txt", initheader = {'Content-Type' => "application/octet-stream", 'X-CSRF-Token' => @csrfToken, 'X-Redmine-API-Key' => @apiKey})
@request.body = @file.read
@response = http.request(@request)

@upToken = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@response.body)['upload']['token']

@secondResponse = RestClient.post 'http://<server_IP_address>/redmine/documents/150/add_attachment.xml', {:multipart => true, :utf8 => "\u2713", :authenticity_token => @csrfToken, :attachments => { "1" => {:filename => "testFile.txt", :description => "Dropbox blabla", :token => @upToken}}, :commit => "Add"}, 'X-Redmine-API-Key' => @apiKey, 'X-CSRF-Token' => @csrfToken, 'Cookie' => cookies[:_redmine_session]
```

As you see I tried to set the `Cookie` header with the data of my session but it doesn't work.

I tried to write the second request with the same library as the first one but I get the same error. Do you know why my user is not recognized? How can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found why the user is set on `anonymous`:

First, I discovered that by adding `logger.info("some text and variables")`in the controller code these informations are going to be displayed in the `<redmine_install_dir>/log/production.log>` file, this is pretty helpful.

In the Redmine `ApplicationController`, a `before_filter` is defined thus some methods are called before the execution of my second request. I took a look at these methods and one of them (`find_current_user`) set the user to `nil` then re-set the user according to some conditions, and I found out that none of these conditions are verified so the user stays `nil`.

So it looks like the problem come from the Redmine API, my `action` seems to be not authorized.

If somebody is interested in this, I can expand my answer by showing part of the Redmine code (althought you can see it on GitHub or somewhere else).